# Filtering out odd numbers and squaring them in a tuple in Python

Tags: python, tuples

This is a question from a school assignment, and appreciate any assistance in pointing out my mistake.

First of all, with respect to the `map()` function in Python, I have been tasked (non-optionable) to redefine it as such to make it specific to a tuple:

```
def map(fn, seq):
    if seq == ():
        return ()
    else:
        return (fn(seq[0]),) + map(fn, seq[1:])
```

Using this, I am supposed to define another function `square_odd(tuple)` that takes in a tuple containing integers as an argument, and specifically square the terms only if they are odd. Essentially, for a tuple input of (5,6,7,8,9), I should be returned (25, 6, 49, 8, 81).

My idea is simply to utilise `lambda` to write a function, paired with an `if` to filter out the odd numbers. Here's what I have:

```
def square_odd(tpl):
    return map(lambda x: x*x if x%2 == 0, tpl)
```

Python has returned me a `SyntaxError` at the comma before `tpl`. Can anyone point out what may be the issue with this? Must I write an `else` condition as well? I have tried adding `else x` but I am only returned the integer value of the first value.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you should write **else statement**.

```
map(lambda x: x*x if x%2 == 1 else x, tp1)
```

and tried this code as simple. And also you should fixed x%2 == 0.
This condition will find even number.

```
return tuple(map(lambda x: x*x if x%2 == 1 else x, tp1))
```

Answer (score 1):

`if` with lambda expects an `else` statement. So it should be like this:

```
def square_odd(tpl):
    return map(lambda x: x if x%2 == 0 else x*x, tpl)
```

Which means, take `x` if `x%2==0` i.e. if it is even, else take `x*x` which is it's square.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not aware that else was necessary. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
def map(fn, seq):
    if seq == ():
        return ()
    else:
        return (fn(seq[0]),) + map(fn, seq[1:])

def square_odd(tpl):
    return map(lambda x: x**2 if x%2 else x, tpl)

t = (1,2,3,4,5)
print(square_odd(t))
```

I have done this and the output is `(1, 2, 9, 4, 25)`.

PS the syntax error raise because the ternary operator `A if condition else B` cannot be used as `A if condition`